# Xamarin.Forms and accessing native control within custom renderers

Tags: xamarin, renderer, xamarin.forms

How to get the reference to the specific native view, not UIView?
This is my custom Label renderer:

```cs
   public class MyLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
   {
       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
       {
            //how to get UILabel reference created by base LabelRender?
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
       }
   }
```

I have used this [Renderer Sample](http://blog.xamarin.com/using-custom-uiviewcontrollers-in-xamarin.forms-on-ios/) as an example.

Answer (score 1):

The reference you used is outdated. Use this one http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/59303

the native view can be accessed through the `Control` property, provided that you called `SetNativeControl()`:

```cs
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<MyCustomView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        if (e.OldElement == null) {
            // perform initial setup
            SetNativeControl (new UIMyCustomView (RectangleF.Empty));
        }

        UpdateSomething ();
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you update your packages via nuget (or the Package Manager on Xamarin Studio).

Answer (score 0):

try using `e.OldElement` or `e.NewElement`

Comment: it is UIView, not UILabel. And it is runtime this so this is the type

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Control property of the renderer. It theoretically should be available in the OnElementChanged method. But, on some platforms like UWP, the custom renderer just literally is the native control.